# left join or similar query

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have a renting schema in my database.

It has 3 tables, user, rentingTrack and lock.

user has as unique element RFIDCode.
in rentingTrack I may have the user(he or she rented at least once) or not (he/she never rented). If the user rented I need the returnLock for the last rent, as rentingID is autoincremented, it is max(rentingID).
With lock table I got the parkingID, the data I need.

[image]

The problem is how to get the parkingID, I have half query:

```
 SELECT  u.userID, l.parkingID

 FROM locks l, user u

LEFT JOIN (SELECT r1.* FROM rentingTrack r1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT userID, MAX(rentingID) maxRentingID FROM rentingTrack GROUP BY userID) r2 
on r1.rentingID = r2.maxRentingID) r on u.userID = r.userID 

 WHERE u.userCodeRFID= 3166681355
```

What i need is, if userID isn't in the rentingTrack table I got:

```
   userID   |  parkingID
  ----------+-----------
        34  |     NULL
```

And if userID is in the rentingTrack

```
   userID   |  parkingID
  ----------+-----------
        34  |        5
```

how can I complete the query to get parkingID?

Comment: I think i will be able to help you.But can you rephrase the Question?

Comment: I need to get parkingID, the query is not completed, because I need the relationship betwenn r.returnLock and locks table to get parkingID. Did I explain it?

Comment: Please provide some example Data.

Comment: You don't have any join condition with `locks`. If you want to get a NULL for `l.parkingID`, you need a LEFT JOIN with locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. (Need some sample data for **duplicates**)

```
select distinct u.userID,l.parkingID
from users
left join rentingTrack r on u.userID=r.userID
left join locks l on r.returnLock=l.lockid
```

Comment: What about the need to get the row of `rentingTrack` with `MAX(rentingID)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  u.userID, l.parkingID

FROM user u

LEFT JOIN (SELECT r1.userID, r1.returnLock
           FROM rentingTrack r1
           INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT userID, MAX(rentingID) maxRentingID
               FROM rentingTrack
               GROUP BY userID) r2 
           ON r1.rentingID = r2.maxRentingID) r on u.userID = r.userID 

LEFT JOIN locks l ON r.returnLock = l.lockID

WHERE u.userCodeRFID= 3166681355
```